# RMarkdown Showing Sub Tabs when not Included? [images included]

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating an RMarkdown using tabset functions to segment my work. Here is how it looks when I knit the document: [image]

However, when I open it to a browser so that I can save it and send it to others I get these tabs that weren't there originally and I dont want these 'undefined' tabs here

[image]

```
Here is my tab logic: 

# Model Segemnts {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## Historical Data & Libraries --tab one here 

--code and tables 

## Weighted Percentile Model Creation --tab two

--code and tables 

## Mapping Model Predictions to Lanes

-- code and tables

### End tabset
```

Comment: Hm. When I use your code in a clean Rmd it works fine. Also when I open it in the browser there are no undefined tabsets appearing.

Comment: Am I creating the tabset functions correctly?

Comment: As far as I can tell: Yes. As I said, your code works fine on my machine. No "undefined" tabs showing up when I open the document in a browser.

Comment: I'm having same problem. The "undefined" tabs show up when I open the html after saving. When I click either "Show All Code" or "Hide All Code" in the top right of the screen the "undefined" tabs go away. But that is not an ideal solution.